# OAuth2 webapp implementing GitHub webhooks, in .Net CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am trying to build an OAuth2 web application that implements [GitHub webhooks](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/).

This seems only to be possible using [AspNetCore 2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks.Receivers.GitHub/1.0.0-preview1-final).

To implement webhooks in my project I first have to reconfigure `services.AddMvc()` in the `startup.cs` to `services.AddMvcCore().AddGitHubWebHooks()`

This generates errors since `MvcCore()` isn't configured to use Razor Pages.

How do I solve this if I want to use my existing scaffolded MVC-structure?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddViews()
            .AddRazorViewEngine()
            .AddGitHubWebHooks();
    }
}
```

*`StartUp.cs` contains al ot more code that I can post it if necessary*

Error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.get_Signature()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__27`2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Please add your code/ exception as text instead of images.  Text is searchable, which will help future users who may have the same issue as yours.

Comment: @chuex
Okej, thanks for the comment. Updated the thread accordingly.

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but I get the same error with the Asp.Net Core Webhooks preview when I build my Autofac container after registering Serilog. Removing Serilog removes the error. All other services I use seem to be working fine with the Asp .Net Core Webhook preview - just Serliog causes System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory' error. Perhaps look to the other code in your startup.cs for something that is not happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [code for AddMvc()](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), you can see how it is adding Razor Pages support. Specifically this code:

```
// Default framework order
builder.AddFormatterMappings();
builder.AddViews();
builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
builder.AddRazorPages();
builder.AddCacheTagHelper();
```

That said, `AddMvcCore()` is conseptually a subset of `AddMvc()`. Given that the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks) project contains both [`IMvcBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks.Receivers.GitHub/Extensions/GitHubMvcBuilderExtensions.cs) and [`IMvcCoreBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHooks.Receivers.GitHub/Extensions/GitHubMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs) extensions (aka `AddMvc` and `AddMvcCore`), you should only need to swap out your method:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddGitHubWebHooks();
    }
}
```